# Predict the height of a student whose weight is 60 kilograms.

Tags: statistics, regression

The average height and weight of a group of students turned out to be
5 ft 6 inches and 65 kilograms respectively. The correlation between
heights and weights was found to be 0.6. Using the regression equation
for predicting weight from height, the estimated weight of a 6 ft tall
student was calculated to be 80 kilograms. Predict the height of a
student whose weight is 60 kilograms

Comment: please give me full solution of it. I can't solve it

Comment: Think about what the equation of the line of best fit (for weight in terms of height) might be.

Comment: Try the model $h(w) = h_0 + \alpha w$. Figure out what $h_0$ and $\alpha$ must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fitted model can be used to predict height from weight using
h= a + bw where a and b are the fitted regression coefficients (intercept and slope respectively).

Now if h=a + bw  (h-a)/b = w.  Use this equation to solve for w given h.

Comment: the correlation between heights and weights is 0.6. then why we assume the linear function

Comment: Linear regression is historically the classical approach first applied by Galton (late 19th cwntury).  If you view the correlation between height and weight to be weak enough that a nonlinear relationship between height and weight might increase the correlation you should try it.  But first look at a scatterplot and the residuals.  It is possible that the scatter plot will show that the linear function best describes how h and w are related and the "low" correlation is strictly due to a large variance for the residuals.